# Display a custom field rating system in the front end

Tags: posts, php, custom-field, functions, rating

I have added a content rating system to my platform where the authors can select which audience their post is appropriate for. Currently, these options are available:

> Unrated
>
> G
>
> PG
>
> R

The code that I use to display the rating options on the post edit page is:

```
// Article Content Rating
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'rating_select_box' );
function rating_select_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'rating_select_box', // id, used as the html id att
        __( 'Content Rating (optional)' ), // meta box title
        'rating_select_cb', // callback function, spits out the content
        'post', // post type or page. This adds to posts only
        'side', // context, where on the screen
        'low' // priority, where should this go in the context
    );

}

function rating_select_cb( $post ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rating', true);
    echo '<div class="misc-pub-section misc-pub-section-last"><span id="timestamp"><label>Article Content Rating: </label>';

    $ratings = array(
        1 => ' G ',
        2 => ' PG ',
        3 => ' R ',
    );

    echo '<select name="rating">';
    echo '<option value=""' . ((($value == '') || !isset($ratings[$value])) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '> Unrated </option>';

    // output each rating as an option
    foreach ($ratings as $id => $text) {
        echo '<option value="' . $id . '"' . (($value == $id) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '">' . $text. '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';

    echo '</span></div>';
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_metadata');

function save_metadata($postid)
{   
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return false;
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $postid ) ) return false;
    if( empty($postid) ) return false;


    if ( is_null($_REQUEST["rating"]) ) {
        delete_post_meta($postid, 'rating');
    } else {
        update_post_meta($postid, 'rating', $_REQUEST['rating']);
    }

}
// END Article Content Rating
```

Now, the problem is, what code do I add to `single.php` to display their choice? So for instance, if the author selected PG, then I want to `echo 'Content Rating: PG';` or if it was on default (unrated), I want to `echo 'Content Rating: Unrated';`. How is this possible? Ideally, a solution that is light on the server as my platform is heavily trafficked.

Answer (score 1):

You are already doing what you need to do, but in another context.

```
$value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rating', true);
```

Take that value and format it for display.

**Edit:** I installed your whole block of code. You are storing you key, not your ratings value. You need to access that `$ratings` array again to pull the value.

```
$ratings = array(
    1 => ' G ',
    2 => ' PG ',
    3 => ' R ',
);

if (!empty($ratings[$value])) {
  echo '<p>Content Rating : '.$ratings[$value].'</p>';
} else {
  echo '<p>Content Rating : Unrated</p>';
}
```

However, even before I spotted the problem I was seeing content echo. "Content Rating: 1" instead of "Content Rating: G". I don't know why you claim to see nothing. If you still see nothing, something is wrong but not with this code.

I made no changes to your original block of code.

Comment: This seems to echo everything as `Content Rating : Unrated` no matter the choice. Do you have a sandbox to test it yourself?

Comment: That 'get_post_meta` line returns a `string` for the appropriate meta_key. It should work. You need to debug. Try `var_dump($post->ID,$value);` right after the `get_post_meta` line.

Comment: I added `var_dump($post->ID,$value);` after the `$value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rating', true);` line and refreshed and tested everything again, what should I be looking for as the same results were displayed? If I sound unexperienced in this matter, it is because I am.

Comment: You want a number followed by a string-- one of your ratings values. Just post the output.

Comment: All that is output is `Content Rating : Unrated`.

Comment: The output of the `var_dump`...

Comment: I would not know where to find that output. When I view the post, all I can find is `<p>Content Rating : Unrated</p>`.

Comment: `var_dump` ***always*** prints something. Are you are sure you looking in the right place?

Comment: Yes certainly. I am looking at where I execute your `if (!empty($value)) {` code. Should I be looking at somewhere different? Do you by any chance have an opportunity to test run this code yourself to check if it works on your system?

Comment: Yes, the part I wrote works on my machine. The problem has to be with some of the rest of you code.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the meta data (`var_dump` or FirePHP), we can see that the meta is stored as an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) with one pair of `$key=>$value`.

The key is always `0` and the value, the number of the selected rating.
E.g.: `array('0'=>'1')` for `G`.

So, this little function returns the correct rating:

```
function wpse_78113_get_rating( $pid )
{
    $ratings = array(
        1 => ' G ',
        2 => ' PG ',
        3 => ' R ',
    );
    $meta = get_post_meta( $pid, 'rating' );
        // var_dump($meta);

    if( empty($meta) || empty($meta[0]) )
        return 'Content rating: Unrated';

    return 'Content rating: ' . $ratings[$meta[0]];
}
```

And use it like: `echo wpse_78113_get_rating( $post->ID );`

Answer (score -2):

```
if ( is_null($_REQUEST["rating"]) ) {
    delete_post_meta($postid, 'rating');
} else {
    update_post_meta($postid, 'rating', $_REQUEST['rating']);
}
```

Does this not need to be $post->ID in the save_meta function?

Comment: Is `$post->ID` haunting you? ;) Look closer, that's the parameter received by `save_metadata($postid)`...